# NSURLConnection GET and POST not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I am not getting the correct output from the server. The response I get back everytime is:

> Gone
>
> ```
> /prod/bwckgens.p_proc_term_datehas been permanently removed from this server.
> ```

This is usually recieved when you just direct the web browser to the page [here](https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckgens.p_proc_term_date) instead of going through [this](https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched?) page first. This makes me come to the conclusion that a cookie isn't being saved, but I read in the documentation that this is all handled by the NSURLConnection object. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

```
#import "PCFViewController.h"

@interface PCFViewController ()

@end

NSMutableData *mutData;

@implementation PCFViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)queryServer {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:3.0];
    //the reason I perform a GET here is just to get a cookie and communicate like a normal web browser, since directly doing a POST to the proper address isn't working
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"text/html; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        mutData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[mutData length]);
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:mutData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //just to see the contents(for debugging)
    NSLog(@"%@", str);

    [self handleConnection:connection];
}

-(void)handleConnection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //this is the first step
    if ([@"/prod/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched" isEqualToString:[[[connection originalRequest] URL] path]]) {
        //first request
        //POST
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckgens.p_proc_term_date"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:3.0];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *args = @"p_calling_proc=bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched&p_term=201320";
        NSData *requestBody = [args dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [request setHTTPBody:requestBody];
        connection = [connection initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];
        if (connection) {
            mutData = [NSMutableData data];
        }
        //second step. Here I send the list of classes(COMPUTER SCIENCE) I want to display as well as the term SPRING2013
    }else if([@"/prod/bwckgens.p_proc_term_date" isEqualToString:[[[connection currentRequest] URL] path]]) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed
                                                           timeoutInterval:3.0];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *args = @"term_in=201320&sel_subj=dummy&sel_day=dummy&sel_schd=dummy&sel_insm=dummy&sel_camp=dummy&sel_levl=dummy&sel_sess=dummy&sel_instr=dummy&sel_ptrm=dummy&sel_attr=dummy&sel_subj=CS&sel_crse=dummy&sel_title=dummy&sel_schd=%25&sel_from_cred=&sel_to_cred=&sel_camp=%25&sel_ptrm=%25&sel_instr=%25&sel_sess=%25&sel_attr=%25&begin_hh=0&begin_mi=0&begin_ap=a&end_hh=0&end_mi=0&end_ap=a";
        NSData *requestBody = [args dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [request setHTTPBody:requestBody];
        connection = [connection initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];
        if (connection) {
            mutData = [NSMutableData data];
        }
        //the courses should be shown now I have to parse the data
    }else if([@"/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec" isEqualToString:[[[connection currentRequest] URL] path]]) {


    }
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@\n", error.description);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [mutData setLength:0];
    NSLog(@"%@\n", response.description);

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [mutData appendData:data];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the Request Object with the same URL Connection once it is started. Read the documentation of NSURLConnection. it says:

> The URL request to load. The request object is deep-copied as part of
>   the initialization process. Changes made to request after this method
>   returns do not affect the request that is used for the loading
>   process.

So if you want to hit another URL, you have to create a new URLRequest and new URLConnection object. regarding your question about saving cookies. you can set the cache policy of the URLRequest using the following method

```
- (void)setCachePolicy:(NSURLRequestCachePolicy)policy
```

Comment: The problem I was having was with the referer not being set, but I will mark this as the accepted answer anyways. Thanks!